# Facebook OAuth box showing Login instead of Allow

Tags: facebook, oauth

The issue I am having is that in the authentication box are login/cancel buttons. This is not what I want, I am wanting it to show Allow/Don't Allow.
I thought this was the default but for some reason it is showing up differently.

I am not sure why this would be happening. Any help on this problem would be much appreciated.
You can view the app at https://apps.facebook.com/found-it-on-carsale/

Comment: I logged in and then I got the allow or don't allow. And when I tried for the second time I didn't ask me login instead allow or dont allow was shown directly. I'm too new let me also wait for some answers....

Answer (score 0):

Basically, user need to login(in other words,authorize the application)...After that,user will  need to allow/dont allow the application...Once the user allow the application,it will not showing allow/dont allow again...The most important thing is,user must login....

Answer (score 0):

Thats a part of protocol.Once user authorize him self or herself for a particular application next time when user will come he/she will be asked to login and since they have already approved access, they will not be asked again.

user will be asked to approve/deny if

1. User changed his/her password.
2. Your application has been disabled for some reason
3. You have changed the scope

Why you want user to approve/deny your access request every time when he has already approved and has shown faith on your application? it will create bad user experience